# My NN in keras predict values always between 0 and 1

Tags: keras

I have written a simple neural network by keras (R API) as follow:

```
  # Creates dense embedding layer; outputs 3D tensor
  # with shape (batch_size, sequence_length, output_dim)
  layer_embedding(input_dim = 100, 
                  output_dim = 30, 
                  input_length = ncol(ttrainx)) %>% 
  #bidirectional(layer_lstm(units = 64)) %>%
  layer_lstm(units = 10) %>% 
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.5) %>% 
  layer_dense(units =2, activation = 'sigmoid')
```

The codes above works without any issue, I am just using 10 sample instances with two outputs (one is the lead of the first one). However, I wonder I always get a prediction between 0 and 1 for my outputs (even I test above on a file with more than 100 training samples), even I am using the same training samples on test:

```
> result
           [,1]      [,2]
 [1,] 0.8137890 0.6513228
 [2,] 0.8190086 0.6572025
 [3,] 0.8033106 0.6475145
 [4,] 0.7816594 0.6308075
 [5,] 0.7592142 0.6084980
 [6,] 0.7806532 0.6365856
 [7,] 0.8263645 0.6561120
 [8,] 0.8299966 0.6609393
 [9,] 0.8048422 0.6523835
[10,] 0.7748901 0.6305881
```

I even use tanh function in the layer output but the outputs are between 0 and 1

```
  layer_dense(units =2, activation = 'tanh')
```

outputs are:

```
          [,1]      [,2]
 [1,] 0.7627973 0.6377947
 [2,] 0.7790936 0.6529062
 [3,] 0.7719792 0.6425777
 [4,] 0.7518294 0.6246758
 [5,] 0.6936694 0.5419450
 [6,] 0.7229034 0.6205049
 [7,] 0.7928969 0.6572189
 [8,] 0.7629467 0.6395736
 [9,] 0.7811863 0.6578141
[10,] 0.7765120 0.6340105
```

Can anyone explain what is the cause of this problem?

Comment: Hi Jole, welcome to Cross-Validated. Please have a look at our help pages, especially those on off-topic questions. This question is off-topic here: next time please ask programming questions on Stackoverflow.  Anyway, just for this time, note that the last layer of your NN uses a sigmoid activation. The sigmoid function maps any real number to a real number between 0 and 1, so....

Comment: Something strange would happen if sigmoid returned beyond (0, 1) and tanh beyond (-1, 1) and if that is not the case, then what exactly is the problem in here..?

Answer (score 2):

You use a sigmoid function in the final layer. The sigmoid function is bounded between 0 and 1. If you want to have different bounds, you'll have to use a different activation function.

Comment: I even use "tanh" function but the outputs are betwenn 0 and 1

Comment: well, my outputs could have very different bounds, for example they are between 1 and 1000, what activation function I should use then?

Comment: If you care about the bounds, then you could just rescale and shift the sigmoid output. But if the output is unbounded in principle (the target variable can take on arbitrarily large or small values), then linear activations are what you want, because they're not constrained.

Comment: It's not unusual for people to re-scale data provided to neural networks. Did you re-scale your target variable to lie in $[0,1]$?